# xampp apache is not starting after php update from 7.2 to 7.4

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

I tried to update PHP7.2 to PHP7.4 for my XAMPP Apache on Windows 10. Now Apache is not starting.

The log error is:

```html
[Fri Jul 23 10:47:04.645093 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15604:tid 764] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jul 23 10:47:07.981978 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5588:tid 704] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jul 23 10:47:10.535573 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15604:tid 764] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5588 exited successfully.
```

The error message from apache is:

```html
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:47:39 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I followed this tutorial:

https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-upgrade-lower-version-to-latest-php-version-in-xampp-on-windows-f7be9a70bbb0

PHP configuration

```html
# # PHP-Module setup 
# 
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll" 
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll" 
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What's in the Apache config regarding PHP?

Comment: @Gerard You mean php module setup??

Comment: Anything regarding PHP in your Apache configuration.  BTW, I notice you were following a how-to about PHP 5, from 2017.  There might have been some subtle changes since then.  Anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: #
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

Comment: Add this to your question.  In comments it's impossible to see what is commented out and what isn't.

Comment: Isn't there an "addhandler" line for PHP?  Or a phpinidir ?

Comment: I have added the code above ..

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer?  Isn't there an "addhandler" line for PHP?